# log transformation of data does not normalize the data

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a phenotype data which is not normally distributed. So I log transformed the data to normalize the data centering to zero. The distribution became better but it is still not normal. What can I do to make it normal or should I proceed with the analysis as such. My goal is to make a co-expression network.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should continue your analysis as such. There is no point in normalizing the data further if the data is simply not normally distributed.

You're trying to fit your model to the data and not your data to the model.

Comment: Thank you! Should I keep the log transformation? As it is not improving the distribution and I have compared the results with transformed and non-transformed data. The latter give better data with the model.

Comment: @Jessica I don't know what type of analysis you are doing. But for example if you're doing a linear regression, one purpose of log-transforming your data is to linearise your data. Say for example the relationship of X and Y is exponential, taking the log of X results in a more linear relationship between Y and log(X).